# How to make one MutationObserver listen for changes on multiple elements?

Tags: jquery

I have implemented the following code for observing changes in class:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    if (mutation.attributeName === "class") {
      var attributeValue = $(mutation.target).prop(mutation.attributeName);
      console.log("Class attribute changed to:", attributeValue);
    }
  });
});

observer.observe(document.querySelector(".xxx"), {
  attributes: true
});  });
```

JSFiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/8Lfj0ev3/

Ideally, I want this to listen for changes in all elements with class 'xxx'. But it is only listening to first element with xxx class and ignoring others. How can I fix this?

Comment: Please use **on-site** Stack Snippets for runnable examples, not off-site links. Stack Snippets are the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two ways to address this:

### Multiple `observe` calls

You can call `observe` multiple times to watch multiple elements:

```
$(".xxx").each(function() {
  observer.observe(this, {
    attributes: true
  });
});
```

Live Example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
      if (mutation.attributeName === "class") {
        var attributeValue = $(mutation.target).prop(mutation.attributeName);
        console.log("Class attribute changed to:", attributeValue);
      }
    });
  });
  
  $(".xxx").each(function() {
    observer.observe(this, {
      attributes: true
    });
  });
});

setTimeout(function() {
  $(".d1").addClass("x1");
}, 800);
setTimeout(function() {
  $(".d2").addClass("x2");
}, 1600);
setTimeout(function() {
  $(".d3").addClass("x3");
}, 2400);
```

```html
<div class="d1 xxx"></div>

<div class="d2 xxx"> </div>

<div class="d3 xxx"> </div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

### Watch container's subtree

But another option is to watch the subtree of the nearest container they're all in and then only pay attention to changes if they occurred within a `.xxx` element:

```
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    if (mutation.attributeName === "class") {
      var $target = $(mutation.target);                            // ***
      if ($target.hasClass("xxx")) {                               // ***
        var attributeValue = $target.prop(mutation.attributeName);
        console.log("Class attribute changed to:", attributeValue);
      }
    }
  });
});

observer.observe(document.body, {                                  // ***
  attributes: true,
  subtree: true                                                    // ***
});
```

Live Example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
      if (mutation.attributeName === "class") {
        var $target = $(mutation.target);
        if ($target.hasClass("xxx")) {
          var attributeValue = $target.prop(mutation.attributeName);
          console.log("Class attribute changed to:", attributeValue);
        }
      }
    });
  });
  
  observer.observe(document.body, {
    attributes: true,
    subtree: true
  });
});

setTimeout(function() {
  $(".d1").addClass("x1");
}, 800);
setTimeout(function() {
  $(".d2").addClass("x2");
}, 1600);
setTimeout(function() {
  $(".d3").addClass("x3");
}, 2400);
```

```html
<div class="d1 xxx"></div>

<div class="d2 xxx"> </div>

<div class="d3 xxx"> </div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

In that example the nearest container is `document.body`, but of course in your real situation there may be something closer to the elements.

Comment: Thank you so much, the first approach worked perfectly!